# Can I travel to Ireland using a refugee document, or do I need a visa?

Tags: paperwork, ireland, refugees

I have a refugee document issued by Italy. Can I travel to Ireland?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since Italy and the Republic of Ireland are both parties to the [European Agreement on the Abolition of Visas for Refugees](https://www.coe.int/en/web/conventions/full-list/-/conventions/treaty/031).

Beware, however, that the UK is *not* an active party, so you cannot transit in, say, London on the way; you have to fly directly from a Schengen airport to Ireland.